# NAS Software as application on my own Linux?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, nas, freenas

I want to install NAS Software (ala FreeNAS, Amahi etc) on my DIY-Linux server but I have one questions:

Most solutions I see are **NAS software with an 'glued' Operating System to it** (e.g. FreeNAS, Amahi). Do they turn my system into an closed Appliance? I want to run **Java/Python daemons** as well as other things (private **GIT Server**) and I am afraid I cannot do this anymore if convert my DIY server into an appliance using a NAS with linked OS?

So essentially I am looking for **NAS software which runs as an application on top of my own OS of choice (Ubuntu most likely).** So the NAS software acts then as a nice web client/wizards/etc. to all services on Linux.

How can I run feature-rich NAS-software on my DIY-server while keeping room/access to run daemons and other non NAS related services?

Tx

Comment: Well, if you’re looking for software, this isn’t the place to ask, try [softwarerecs.se]. However, the most important question is: Do you need a nice GUI to manage shares, quota and whatnot? Because if you don’t, all you need is Samba and a NFS server.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, things like FreeNAS use a customised Linux or NetBSD OS as the base and so it should be easy enough to run other software - indeed, that is one of the reasons for using them.

On the other hand, any Linux, BSD, Mac or Windows based device can be turned into a simple NAS since a NAS is just a way of accessing storage over a network. Normally using SMB since most client devices tend to be Windows. But there are plenty of other connection methods too.

The dedicated NAS OS's simply try to make the configuration and running simpler. If you are prepared to learn some Linux configuration magic then any of the Linux distributions would do you - I'd recommend Debian as it is stable, simple and well supported.